# Replace String in Specific line in text file

Tags: c#, string

I want to replace String1 with String2 in Text file.

**Text File** :

```
This is line no 1. 
This is line no 2. 
This is line no 3.
This is line no 4. 
This is line no 5. 
This is line no 6.
```

**String is** :

```
String1 : no
string2 : number
```

I want this type of output line 3 to 5 replace with "no" to "number":

```
This is line no 1. 
This is line no 2. 
This is line number 3.
This is line number 4. 
This is line number 5. 
This is line no 6.
```

Comment: You always want to replace only line 3-5?

Comment: Read the file with eg `ReadAllLines`, find the lines you want, perform the replacement and write them out again.

Comment: As @MightyBadaboom says, we need to understand the question better, in terms of how to tell whether a line should be changed or not. Then you should show the code that you've tried and how it doesn't do what you want. _Then_ we'll be able to give you proper, useful, directed help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach with `Linq`

```
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\yourfile.txt");
file = file.Select((x, i) => i > 1 && i < 5 ? x.Replace("no", "number") : x).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\yourfile.txt", file);
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(string path)` may help you.

It creates string array from Text File, you edit the array, and save it with `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines`.

```
string[] Strings = File.ReadAllLines(/*File Path Here*/);
Strings[2] = Strings[2].Replace("no", "number");
Strings[3] = Strings[3].Replace("no", "number");
Strings[4] = Strings[4].Replace("no", "number");
File.WriteAllLines(/*File Path Here*/, Strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
// Read all lines from text file.
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("path to file");
for(int i = 3; i <= 5; i++) // From line 3 to line 5
{
    // Replace 'no' to 'number' in 3 - 5 lines
    lines[i - 1] = lines[i - 1].Replace("no", "number");
}

// Rewrite lines to file
File.WriteAllLines("path to file", lines);
```

Comment: this will throw error since the older file is not disposed

Comment: @Grijan actually no, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadAllLines?view=net-7.0): `File.ReadAllLines()` _Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array, and then closes the file._